# Group by Clause causing duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the following query and it is giving me duplicate entries of 8 employees. For Example:

```
EMPLOYEE    FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   PL_1    PL_2    PL_3    PL_4    PL_5    PL_6 DUAL_EMPLOYEE  Dual_Process_Level_Comparison   process_level_compare
15723   BARBARA         FERREIRA                        LSBCW   LSBCR   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL     
15723   BARBARA         FERREIRA                        LSBCW   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
```

Barbara should only have 1 record and it should look like:

```
15723   BARBARA         FERREIRA                        LSBCW   LSBCR   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
```

I noticed that it appears to be an issues with the a.process group by statement.

```
   select 
              a.EMPLOYEE, 
              m.FIRST_NAME, 
              m.LAST_NAME, 
              m.PROCESS_LEVEL as PL_1, 
              max(case when a.POS_LEVEL = 2 then a.process end) as PL_2, 
              max(case when a.POS_LEVEL = 3 then a.process end) as PL_3, 
              max(case when a.POS_LEVEL = 4 then a.process end) as PL_4, 
              max(case when a.POS_LEVEL = 5 then a.process end) as PL_5, 
              max(case when a.POS_LEVEL = 6 then a.process end) as PL_6, 
              case when s.[DUAL EMPLOYEE] = 'UNASSIGNED' then ' ' else s.[DUAL EMPLOYEE] end as DUAL_EMPLOYEE, 
              case when a.process = s.[DUAL EMPLOYEE] then 'REVIEW' end as Dual_Process_Level_Comparison, 

              case 
                when a.process in ('test') then 1 
                when a.process in ('test2', 'test3') then 2 
                   when a.process in ('test4', 'test5', 'test6') then 3 
                   when a.process in ('test7', 'test', 'LSBCW', 'LTBC', 'LTBH', 'LTBV', 'LTCLR', 'LTCS', 'LTHC', 'LTMON', 'LTSBC') then 4 
                   when a.process in ('hi') then 5 
                   when a.process in ('kkkkk') then 6 
                   when a.process in ('aaaa') then 7 
                   when a.process in ('ttttt') then 8 
                   when a.process in ('oooo') then 9 
                   when a.process in ('aaaaaa') then 10 
                   when a.process in ('testest', 'def', 'ghi') then 11 
              end as Supplemental_Compare_Number
            from 
              dbo.vw_PAEMPPOS a 
              join dbo.COMPLETE_EMPLOYEE_MASTER m on m.EMPLOYEE = a.EMPLOYEE 
              join dbo.HR_EMPUSERFIELDS s on s.EMPLOYEE = m.EMPLOYEE 

            where END_DATE = '2099-12-31 00:00:00.000' 
              and EMP_STATUS NOT IN ('1A', 'RT', 'SZ', 'T1', 'XD', 'XV', 'ZZ') 
            group by 
              a.EMPLOYEE, 
              m.LAST_NAME, 
              m.FIRST_NAME, 
              m.PROCESS_LEVEL, 
              s.[DUAL EMPLOYEE],
              a.process
```

I found the issue to be with the a.process group by statement which is giving me the extra employee values. Is there anyway for me to take out the a.process in the group by to get the query to run? dbo.vw_PROD.process is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause is the error I receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one row per employee, then your `GROUP BY` clause should be:

```
group by a.EMPLOYEE
```

Period.  No other columns, unless you *know* that there is only one value per employee.  So, the names might be ok.

Use appropriate aggregation columns on the rest of the columns.  You can use `MIN()` and `MAX()` (either one) for the names.

Comment: When I do take out the others for the group by, how do I get past the error of not having the rest inside the group by or aggregate function? You are saying to put Min or Max on the rest of the columns then?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @donkeykong213 . . . As I explain in the answer, you use aggregation functions, such as `MAX(Last_Name)`.